# Lock/Unlock all vertex groups weights

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have many Vertex Groups created. I would like to be able to lock/unlock all vertex groups instead of having to click the "lock" icon on all vertex groups individually. Is there anyway of doing this? Or does anyone know of a plugin or add-on which exists to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of that particular button until just now. Have to wait 3 minutes to mark the answer as accepted for some reason.

Comment: @TTTTTTa no worries, I'm glad I was able to help :)